# I want to use totalmon and totalcost in my select query instead of select *

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use totalmon and totalcost in my select query instead of select *

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (  SELECT
             SUM(il.linecost) AS totalcost
            ,DATENAME(m,il.actualdate) AS totalmon 
            FROM invuseline il
            LEFT JOIN glcomponents g ON g.compvalue = il.gldebitacct
            INNER JOIN invuse i ON i.invusenum = il.invusenum AND i.siteid = il.siteid
            INNER JOIN workorder w ON w.wonum = il.refwo and w.siteid = il.siteid
            WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),il.actualdate,120) BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2020-01-31')
            AND il.usetype = 'ISSUE'
            AND i.status = 'COMPLETE'
            GROUP BY DATENAME(m,il.actualdate)
        ) AS t

    PIVOT(  SUM(t.totalcost)
            FOR t.totalmon IN ( [January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December])
        ) AS pivot_table
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 Invalid column name 'totalcost'.

[image]

Comment: You should learn to format your query. Even with jarlh's edit it is still unintelligible

Comment: I would like to help but I can't even read this query. Please edit it to a legible format.

Comment: by mistake its wriiten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT
--in select we give column names. column names are given below
--Can't able to select totalcost because it is column value
  [January],
[February],
[March],
[April],
[May],
[June],
[July],
[August],
[September],
[October],
[November],
[December]
FROM (SELECT
  SUM(invuseline.linecost) AS totalcost,
  DATENAME(m, invuseline.actualdate) AS totalmon
FROM invuseline
LEFT JOIN glcomponents
  ON glcomponents.compvalue = invuseline.gldebitacct
INNER JOIN invuse
  ON invuse.invusenum = invuseline.invusenum
  AND invuse.siteid = invuseline.siteid
INNER JOIN workorder
  ON workorder.wonum = invuseline.refwo
  AND workorder.siteid = invuseline.siteid
WHERE (CONVERT(varchar(10), invuseline.actualdate, 120) BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2020-01-31')
AND invuseline.usetype = 'ISSUE'
AND invuse.status = 'COMPLETE'
GROUP BY DATENAME(m, invuseline.actualdate)) AS totat
PIVOT (
SUM(totat.totalcost)
FOR totat.totalmon IN (
[January],
[February],
[March],
[April],
[May],
[June],
[July],
[August],
[September],
[October],
[November],
[December])
) AS pivot_table
```

Cannot select `totalcost` because it is column value